# org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@114a85c2 has been closed already

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I found below exception after loading springboot.

```
[2020-01-06 20:03:39.173][main      (1)][WARN ][o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.task.scheduling-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingProperties': Could not bind properties to 'TaskSchedulingProperties' : prefix=spring.task.scheduling, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@114a85c2 has been closed already
```

I don’t understand this error.
Please let me know why this exception is generated.